Why Do I Get INSTALL_BASELINE_PROFILE_FAILED When Running the App?
I am using AGP 8.7.1 with Android Studio Ladybug:
Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-242.23339.11.2421.12483815, built on October 10, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
macOS 14.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 5120M
Cores: 10
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
  ide.instant.shutdown=false
  ide.experimental.ui=true
  i18n.locale=
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  idea.plugin.protoeditor (242.23339.11)
  io.github.composegears.valkyrie (0.9.1)
  org.norbye.tor.kdocformatter (1.6.5)
  com.jetbrains.kmm (0.8.3(242)-4)
  org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.ide (1.7.0)

I have a project that works great with a debug build. I set up signing for the release build using a custom keystore, and when I run it, I get a cryptic error message centered around INSTALL_BASELINE_PROFILE_FAILED:

The application could not be installed: INSTALL_BASELINE_PROFILE_FAILED Installation failed due to: 'Baseline profile did not install"

Why am I getting this and what can I do to fix it?

Actually, I'm seeing this as an issue only on android 15 devices. Similar for you?

@Chris: That was nearly a month ago, and I forget what I all tested on. Sorry!

For me, it started happening while installing on Android 15 devices.
In the Run debug configuration,
Run -> Edit Configurations
Selecting APK from app bundle solved the issue


actually in LadyBug, the menu is called Run > "Edit Configurations ...". Thank you a lot for the tip.

thanks@frank. Added path in the answer

You already have a build installed on this device with the same applicationId but a different signing key. A common scenario for this: you have a debug build signed by your normal debug keystore. Android is trying to install a replacement build with a different signing key, and that will not work.
Assuming that you want to be able to use both builds on the same device, you need to give them distinct applicationId values. For the debug scenario described above, the simple solution is to use applicationIdSuffix:
android {
    // cool stuff goes here

    buildTypes {
        // more cool stuff goes here

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
        }
    }
}

(the above is for build.gradle.kts; adjust as needed for build.gradle and Groovy syntax)
Now, if your applicationId in defaultConfig is com.commonsware.awesomeapp, your debug build will get an applicationId of com.commonsware.awesomeapp.debug. Now you can have both your debug and your release builds installed side by side with different signing keys.

Interestingly, this did solve the problem of installing the app but I still get the profile install failing error too.

Also bear in mind, if you have setup crashlytics / firebase before you add this suffix directive, running the debug version will require an updated google-services.json or you'll end up with a No matching client found for package name error.
